# How to check if CUDA GPUs are available in R?

Tags: r, gpu, xgboost

I am writing a script that uses `xgboost` package to train machine learning models in R. The model training can be accelerated if CUDA GPUs are available and the GPU version of the package is installed.

Is there a function that can check if GPUs are available (preferably without installing additional package other than `xgboost`)?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the GPUs available for your project and zone via gce_list_gpus()

Try This:
gce_list_gpus(project="your-project")

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, it seems that `googleComputeEngineR` package is needed. Is there a way to check GPU only use the base R packages and the `xgboost` R package?